# Problem re-entering Schengen Area?

Tags: schengen, buses, passport-stamps

I entered Schengen area via airplane in Geneva March 2016 and passport got stamped. But when I left by bus from Hungary my passport was not even scanned or stamped. Will I have problem re-entering Schengen again; it has been two years and I only have entry stamp?

I heard that after 180 it has no problems.

I have Serbian Passport.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but let me add that more than 180 [days?] will not help _at all_, as it makes it appear your _apparent_ but spurious overstay was even longer. Start looking for your bus ticket, or evidence such as a Serbian entry stamp, that you did leave.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus i do not have duplicate passport. i only heard that i can get a new entry stamp because they cant track history where i left because i wasnt caght overstaying in schengen